# Jquery transition Opacity based on var value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to animate an opacity value from 0 to 1, based on the scroll position within the viewport height. The code below sets variables for `windowHeight` and `scrollTop`, which can be combined to calculate `percentageScrolled` (0–100) of the viewport height. Based on this I am able to switch CSS values at set points, but instead I want to gradually change the opacity from 0–100 of `percentageScrolled`.

How can I adjust the code below to transition/animate the opacity?

Thanks.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    // Vars
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var percentageScrolled = (scrollTop*100)/windowHeight;

    if( percentageScrolled < 100 ) {
        $('.colour-overlay').css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
        $('.colour-overlay').css('opacity', '0');
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you mean set the opacity relative to the percentage scrolled or just an animation when it reaches 100?

Comment: Sorry, set the opacity relative to the percentage scrolled. So 0% scrolled = opacity:0, 50% scrolled = opacity: .5, 100% scrolled = opacity: 1

Comment: `$('.colour-overlay').css('opacity', percentageScrolled/100);` -something like this?

Comment: your if statement will never get into the else part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `if` and set the opacity to the percentage divided by 100

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  // Vars
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.colour-overlay').css('opacity', scrollTop / windowHeight);

});
```

```css
.colour-overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="colour-overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(‘.colour-overlay’).css(opacity, percentageScrolled / 100);
```

Instead of if else statement.
Also as a general advice try to avoid using var, use const or let instead and if your project doesnt depend on jquery try to avoid it too.

```
const overlays = document.querySelectorAll(‘.colour-overlay’);
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

    const windowHeight = window.offsetHeight;
    const scrollTop = window.scrollTop;
    const percentageScrolled = (scrollTop * 100) / windowHeight;

    for (const overlay of overlays) {
        overlay.style.opacity = percentageScrolled / 100;
    }

});
```

This would be the pure js solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if i understood you right, but a wrote an example have a look.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){

    // Vars
  // use body instead of window, body will return the right height where window will return the view size
    var windowHeight = $("body").height(); 
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var percentageScrolled = Math.abs((((scrollTop / windowHeight) * 100) / 100 ));
  $('.colour-overlay').css('opacity', percentageScrolled);

});
```

```css
.colour-overlay{
background:red;
height:1000px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colour-overlay"></div>
```